# Find the dot product of orthogonal unit vectors u, v; and w = au + bv

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, orthogonality

$\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal unit vectors and $\vec{w} = a\vec{u} + b\vec{v}$.

Find $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u}$ and $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{v}$.

(Answer should be in terms of the constants $a$ and $b$)

**EDIT:**

Oh boy, I was completely overthinking this. It is basically a really simple algebra problem. Here, I will show you how simple it is, on the off-chance that you are as bad at math as I am.

$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u} = (a\vec{u} + b\vec{v})\cdot\vec{u}$

$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u} = a\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u} + b\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u}$

$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u} = a(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}) + b(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u})$

Since $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u} = 1$ and $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{u} = 0$ because $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal, we get:

$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u} = a(1) + b(0)$

$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u} = a$

Do the same thing for $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{v}$ and you get $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{v} = b$

Comment: May i ask you where did you stuck

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What are your own efforts to solve this? This is not a "do my homework for me"-forum. Have you tried to use the bilinearity of the dot product?

Comment: Sorry for asking without showing my efforts, my attempts were so pathetic that I didn't want to share them. I have no idea how to solve the problem. I've never heard of bilinearity before and this problem looks nothing like the problems in the book. I'm not looking for an answer. I'm just looking for the correct way to approach this problem and get started. I'm in multivariable calculus. I know that u and v are orthogonal directions while a and b are the magnitudes. I just can't wrap my mind around how to relate these variables together.

Comment: I see now, that w dot u = a (u dot av = 0 and u dot bu = b * 1 = b) and using the same process, w dot v = b. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take note of what this exercise tells you about the coordinates of a vector relative to an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal then $u\cdot v=0$. Since they are unit vectors, $u\cdot u=1$ and $v\cdot v=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you give me one that involves $\vec{w}$?

Comment: Since the scalar product is bilinear, $u\cdot w=u\cdot(au+bv)=au\cdot u+bu\cdot v$.

Comment: Oh... that's exactly what I needed to know. I was overthinking this. Thank you for your help. I see now, that w dot u = a (u dot av = 0 and u dot bu = b * 1 = b) and using the same process, w dot v = b.